# Get new fields using existing string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

How to split string into multiple columns in SQL Server?
Here  before first space  value consider as firstname and last space after values consider as lastname and between first and lastspace values consider as middle name.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpHistory](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](500) NULL
) 
INSERT [dbo].[EmpHistory] ([id], [name]) VALUES (1, N'abc nani ravi jai')
INSERT [dbo].[EmpHistory] ([id], [name]) VALUES (2, N'rani xy')
INSERT [dbo].[EmpHistory] ([id], [name]) VALUES (3, N'ravi')
INSERT [dbo].[EmpHistory] ([id], [name]) VALUES (4, N'hari go pani')
INSERT [dbo].[EmpHistory] ([id], [name]) VALUES (5, N'pani gh hani gov hani')
```

Based on above data I want out put like below

```
id | Firstname | middlename     | Last name 
1  |  abc      | nani ravi      |jai
2  |rani       |                |xy
3  |ravi       |                |
4  |hari       |go              |pani
5  |pani       |gh hani gov     |hani
```

I have tried like below

```
select substring(name ,charindex(name,''),len(name))firstname,
substring(reverse(name) ,charindex(reverse(name),''),len(name))lasttname
from EmpHistory
```

Above query getting error.

Can someone please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: **Always** post the exact error when you get an error. Also are you using version 2012 or 2016? Only tag the version you are using.

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/786401/get-new-fields-using-existing-string-in-sql-server.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XML and XQuery. XQuery data model is based on *ordered sequences*. Exactly what we need for the task.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, name NVARCHAR(500) NULL); 
INSERT @tbl (name) VALUES 
(N'abc nani ravi jai'),
(N'rani xy'),
(N'ravi'),
(N'hari go pani'),
(N'pani gh hani gov hani');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.*
    , Firstname = c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
    , Middlename = c.query('data(/root/r[position() gt 1 and position() lt last()])')
        .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(500)')
    , Lastname = IIF(cnt > 1, c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),'')
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE([name], @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.value('count(/root/r)', 'INT')) AS t2(cnt);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| id |         name          | Firstname | Middlename  | Lastname |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
|  1 | abc nani ravi jai     | abc       | nani ravi   | jai      |
|  2 | rani xy               | rani      |             | xy       |
|  3 | ravi                  | ravi      |             |          |
|  4 | hari go pani          | hari      | go          | pani     |
|  5 | pani gh hani gov hani | pani      | gh hani gov | hani     |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we use a CTE to get the position of the first and last spaces and then use them in the main query.

> ```
> with cte as
> (select 
>   name,
>   charindex(' ',name) fi,
>   len(name) l,
>   charindex(' ',reverse(name))la
> from EmpHistory
> )
> select
>   *,
>   case when fi = 0 then name
>     else left(name,fi) end
>     as  first_name,
>   case when fi + la < l+1 and
>     la > 0 then 
>     substring (name,fi + 1,l - fi - la)
>     else '' end as middle_names,
>   case when fi = 0 then ''
>     else right(name,la) end
>     as last_name
> from cte
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name                  | fi |  l | la | first_name | middle_names | last_name
> :-------------------- | -: | -: | -: | :--------- | :----------- | :--------
> abc nani ravi jai     |  4 | 17 |  4 | abc        | nani ravi    |  jai     
> rani xy               |  5 |  7 |  3 | rani       |              |  xy      
> ravi                  |  0 |  4 |  0 | ravi       |              |          
> hari go pani          |  5 | 12 |  5 | hari       | go           |  pani    
> pani gh hani gov hani |  5 | 21 |  5 | pani       | gh hani gov  |  hani
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=17aa542001abd696fb556fd3bacc59a2)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using a bit of JSON and conditional aggregation

**To be clear**... Parsing names is a slippery slope, but if Pos1 is First and PosL is last name and everything else is middle.

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  EmpHistory A
 Cross Apply (
                Select FirstName = coalesce(max(case when [key]=1   then value end),'')
                      ,MiddleName= coalesce(string_agg(case when [key]>1 and [key]<cnt then value end,' ') within group (order by [key]),'')
                      ,LastName  = coalesce(max(case when [key]=Cnt and Cnt>1 then value end),'')
                 From (
                       Select [Key] = [key]+1
                             ,Value
                             ,Cnt = sum(1) over()
                        From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(Name,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' )
                      ) B1
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
id  name                    FirstName   MiddleName   LastName
1   abc nani ravi jai       abc         nani ravi    jai
2   rani xy                 rani                     xy
3   ravi                    ravi        
4   hari go pani            hari        go           pani
5   pani gh hani gov hani   pani        gh hani gov  hani
```